# Having 2 possible cases in regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have 2 cases of outcome of a string, and I want to get the numbers out of it.

The first one is `<@&!302050872383242240>`
And the second one is `<@&302050872383242240>`

Is it possible to get only the numbers of this regex or remove <@&!> and <@&> out of this string?

Comment: How better do you want me to explain this? (whoever downvoted). I don't know what else you need except a string. Holy damn lol.

Comment: You know the problem is that you are supposed to give us the code you tried. We are not expected to just produce it for you, ps. I didn't downvote you

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks @Vickel

Comment: Next time, try to post what you tried. The reason being, sure you have a problem, but at least you're showing research and effort, people can also point to some specific problem in your code, and not make Stack Overflow become a free coding service. Given the simplicity of the task, not that grave, but just as a reminder, read [ask]

Comment: @Lmao123 For some reason I agree with you, I always upheld that idea. If you don't have all the ingredients of a recipe, you shouldn't show what you did with half of them. But rules are rules and we have to follow the guidelines of this site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^<@&\!?(\d+)>$
```

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `\!?` matches the character ! literally (case sensitive)
- `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- **1st Capturing Group** `(\d+)`

  - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGAa1D/1)

Comment: Yup, thank you very much.